# Do all of the Emirates in the UAE have the same visa policy for Indian citizens, or does it vary?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, uae

I'm thinking of meeting up with some Indian friends in the UAE next year, as it's roughly half way. At this point, we're fairly flexible about which of the Emirates we head to.

Does the UAE have a common visa policy for Indian Nationals? Or is there one Emirate where getting them a tourist visa will be simpler?

(Bonus marks - are all visa / immigration things in the UAE at the federal level, or do they sometimes vary between Emirates?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emirati immigrations is a federal agency, hence visa rules are the same for all Emirates. The visas are issued for all the country under the name of UAE and not for a single Emirate or under its name.

Comment: We can probably re-tag a bunch of Dubai visa related questions here then!